# Python Regex to Extract Genome Sequence

Tags: regex, python-2.7, genome

I’m trying to use a Python Regular Expression to extract a genome sequence from a genome database; I’ve pasted a snippet of the database below.

```
>GSVIVT01031739001 pacid=17837850 polypeptide=GSVIVT01031739001 locus=GSVIVG01031739001 ID=GSVIVT01031739001.Genoscope12X annot-version=Genoscope.12X ATGAAAACGGAACTCTTTCTAGGTCATTTCCTCTTCAAACAAGAAAGAAGTAAAAGTTGCATACCAAATATGGACTCGAT TTGGAGTCGTAGTGCCCTGTCCACAGCTTCGGACTTCCTCACTGCAATCTACTTCGCCTTCATCTTCATCGTCGCCAGGT TTTTCTTGGACAGATTCATCTATCGAAGGTTGGCCATCTGGTTATTGAGCAAGGGAGCTGTTCCATTGAAGAAAAATGAT GCTACACTGGGAAAAATTGTAAAATGTTCGGAGTCTTTGTGGAAACTAACATACTATGCAACTGTTGAAGCATTCATTCT TGCTATTTCCTACCAAGAGCCATGGTTTAGAGATTCAAAGCAGTACTTTAGAGGGTGGCCAAATCAAGAGTTGACGCTTC CCCTCAAGCTTTTCTACATGTGCCAATGTGGGTTCTACATCTACAGCATTGCTGCCCTTCTTACATGGGAAACTCGCAGG AGGGATTTCTCTGTGATGATGTCTCATCATGTAGTCACTGTTATCCTAATTGGGTACTCATACATATCAAGTTTTGTCCG GATCGGCTCAGTTGTCCTTGCCCTGCACGATGCAAGTGATGTCTTCATGGAAGCTGCAAAAGTTTTTAAATATTCTGAGA AGGAGCTTGCAGCAAGTGTGTGCTTTGGATTTTTTGCCATCTCATGGCTTGTCCTACGGTTAATATTCTTTCCCTTTTGG GTTATCAGTGCATCAAGCTATGATATGCAAAATTGCATGAATCTATCGGAGGCCTATCCCATGTTGCTATACTATGTTTT CAATACAATGCTCTTGACACTACTTGTGTTCCATATATACTGGTGGATTCTTATATGCTCAATGATTATGAGACAGCTGA AAAATAGAGGACAAGTTGGAGAAGATATAAGATCTGATTCAGAGGACGATGAATAG
>GSVIVT01031740001 pacid=17837851 polypeptide=GSVIVT01031740001 locus=GSVIVG01031740001 ID=GSVIVT01031740001.Genoscope12X annot-version=Genoscope.12X ATGGGTATTACTACTTCCCTCTCATATCTTTTATTCTTCAACATCATCCTCCCAACCTTAACGGCTTCTCCAATACTGTT TCAGGGGTTCAATTGGGAATCATCCAAAAAGCAAGGAGGGTGGTACAACTTCCTCATCAACTCCATTCCTGAACTATCTG CCTCTGGAATCACTCATGTTTGGCTTCCTCCACCCTCTCAGTCTGCTGCATCTGAAGGGTACCTGCCAGGAAGGCTTTAT GATCTCAATGCATCCCACTATGGTACCCAATATGAACTAAAAGCATTGATAAAGGCATTTCGCAGCAATGGGATCCAGTG CATAGCAGACATAGTTATAAACCACAGGACTGCTGAGAAGAAAGATTCAAGAGGAATATGGGCCATCTTTGAAGGAGGAA CCCCAGATGATCGCCTTGACTGGGGTCCATCTTTTATCTGCAGTGATGACACTCTTTTTTCTGATGGCACAGGAAATCCT GATACTGGAGCAGGCTTCGATCCTGCTCCAGACATTGATCATGTAAACCCCCGGGTCCAGCGAGAGCTATCAGATTGGAT GAATTGGTTAAAGATTGAAATAGGCTTTGCTGGATGGCGATTCGATTTTGCTAGAGGATACTCCCCAGATTTTACCAAGT TGTATATGGAAAACACTTCGCCAAACTTTGCAGTAGGGGAAATATGGAATTCTCTTTCTTATGGAAATGACAGTAAGCCA AACTACAACCAAGATGCTCATCGGCGTGAGCTTGTGGACTGGGTGAAAGCTGCTGGAGGAGCAGTGACTGCATTTGATTT TACAACCAAAGGGATACTCCAAGCTGCAGTGGAAGGGGAATTGTGGAGGCTGAAGGACTCAAATGGAGGGCCTCCAGGAA TGATTGGCTTAATGCCTGAAAATGCTGTGACTTTCATAGATAATCATGACACAGGTTCTACACAAAAAATTTGGCCATTC CCATCAGACAAAGTCATGCAGGGATATGTTTATATCCTCACTCATCCTGGGATTCCATCCATATTCTATGACCACTTCTT TGACTGGGGTCTGAAGGAGGAGATTTCTAAGCTGATCAGTATCAGGACCAGGAACGGGATCAAACCCAACAGTGTGGTGC GTATTCTGGCATCTGACCCAGATCTTTATGTAGCTGCCATAGATGAGAAAATCATTGCTAAGATTGGACCAAGGTATGAT GTTGGGAACCTTGTACCTTCAACCTTCAAACTTGCCACCTCTGGCAACAATTATGCTGTGTGGGAGAAACAGTAA
>GSVIVT01031741001 pacid=17837852 polypeptide=GSVIVT01031741001 locus=GSVIVG01031741001 ID=GSVIVT01031741001.Genoscope12X annot-version=Genoscope.12X ATGTCCAAATTAACTTATTTATTATCTCGGTACATGCCAGGAAGGCTTTATGATCTGAATGCATCCAAATATGGCACCCA AGATGAACTGAAAACACTGATAAAGGTGTTTCACAGCAAGGGGGTCCAGTGCATAGCAGACATAGTTATAAACCACAGAA CTGCAGAGAAGCAAGACGCAAGAGGAATATGGCCATCTTTGAAGGAGGAACCCCAGATGATCGCCTTGACTGGACCCCAT CTTTCCTTTGCAAGGACGACACTCCTTATTCCGACGGCACCGGAAACCCTGATTCTGGAGATGACTACAGTGCCGCACCA GACATCGACCACATCAACCCACGGGTTCAGCAAGAGCTAA
```

What I’m trying to do is get the genome (ACGT) sequence for GSVIV01031740001 (the middle sequence), and none of the others. My current regex is

```
sequence = re.compile('(?<=>GSVIVT01031740001) pacid=.*annot-version=.*\n[ACGT\n]*[^(?<!>GSVIVT01031740001) pacid]’)
```

with my logic being find the header with the genbank ID for the correct organism, give me that line, then go to a new line and give me all ACGT and new lines until I get to a header for an organism with a different genbank ID. This fails to give any results.

Yes, I know that re.compile doesn’t actually perform a search; I’m searching against a file opened as ‘target’ so my execution looks like

```
>>> for nucl in target:
...     if re.search(sequence, nucl):
...         print(nucl)
```

Can someone tell me what I’m doing wrong, either in my regex or by using regex in the first place? When I try this on [regex101.com,](http://www.regex101.com) it works, but when I try it in the Python interpreter (2.7.1), it fails.

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I expect a string of ACGT's that match the middle sequence (those that follow GSVIVT01031740001 and come before GSVIVT01031741001)

Comment: sir, step away from that re module!

Comment: @hop do you have a better solution? I wish I could step away from it, but it's the best I can with my limited knowledge of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , you want JUST the genomic sequence for a given locus. So You can do something like this.(assumes your data is in a file)

```
lines = [line.split(' ') for line in open('results.txt') ]
somedict = {}
for each in lines:
    locus =  each[3].split('=')[-1]
    seq = ''.join(each[6:])
    somedict[locus] = seq

print somedict
```

It outputs  a dictionary with the `locus` as key and `sequence` as value

```
{'GSVIVG01031741001': 'ATGTCCAAATTAACTTATTTATTATCTCGGTACATGCCAGGAAGGCTTTATGATCTGAATGCATCCAAATATGGCACCCAAGATGAACTGAAAACACTGATAAAGGTGTTTCACAGCAAGGGGGTCCAGTGCATAGCAGACATAGTTATAAACCACAGAACTGCAGAGAAGCAAGACGCAAGAGGAATATGGCCATCTTTGAAGGAGGAACCCCAGATGATCGCCTTGACTGGACCCCATCTTTCCTTTGCAAGGACGACACTCCTTATTCCGACGGCACCGGAAACCCTGATTCTGGAGATGACTACAGTGCCGCACCAGACATCGACCACATCAACCCACGGGTTCAGCAAGAGCTAA\n', 'GSVIVG01031740001': 'ATGGGTATTACTACTTCCCTCTCATATCTTTTATTCTTCAACATCATCCTCCCAACCTTAACGGCTTCTCCAATACTGTTTCAGGGGTTCAATTGGGAATCATCCAAAAAGCAAGGAGGGTGGTACAACTTCCTCATCAACTCCATTCCTGAACTATCTGCCTCTGGAATCACTCATGTTTGGCTTCCTCCACCCTCTCAGTCTGCTGCATCTGAAGGGTACCTGCCAGGAAGGCTTTATGATCTCAATGCATCCCACTATGGTACCCAATATGAACTAAAAGCATTGATAAAGGCATTTCGCAGCAATGGGATCCAGTGCATAGCAGACATAGTTATAAACCACAGGACTGCTGAGAAGAAAGATTCAAGAGGAATATGGGCCATCTTTGAAGGAGGAACCCCAGATGATCGCCTTGACTGGGGTCCATCTTTTATCTGCAGTGATGACACTCTTTTTTCTGATGGCACAGGAAATCCTGATACTGGAGCAGGCTTCGATCCTGCTCCAGACATTGATCATGTAAACCCCCGGGTCCAGCGAGAGCTATCAGATTGGATGAATTGGTTAAAGATTGAAATAGGCTTTGCTGGATGGCGATTCGATTTTGCTAGAGGATACTCCCCAGATTTTACCAAGTTGTATATGGAAAACACTTCGCCAAACTTTGCAGTAGGGGAAATATGGAATTCTCTTTCTTATGGAAATGACAGTAAGCCAAACTACAACCAAGATGCTCATCGGCGTGAGCTTGTGGACTGGGTGAAAGCTGCTGGAGGAGCAGTGACTGCATTTGATTTTACAACCAAAGGGATACTCCAAGCTGCAGTGGAAGGGGAATTGTGGAGGCTGAAGGACTCAAATGGAGGGCCTCCAGGAATGATTGGCTTAATGCCTGAAAATGCTGTGACTTTCATAGATAATCATGACACAGGTTCTACACAAAAAATTTGGCCATTCCCATCAGACAAAGTCATGCAGGGATATGTTTATATCCTCACTCATCCTGGGATTCCATCCATATTCTATGACCACTTCTTTGACTGGGGTCTGAAGGAGGAGATTTCTAAGCTGATCAGTATCAGGACCAGGAACGGGATCAAACCCAACAGTGTGGTGCGTATTCTGGCATCTGACCCAGATCTTTATGTAGCTGCCATAGATGAGAAAATCATTGCTAAGATTGGACCAAGGTATGATGTTGGGAACCTTGTACCTTCAACCTTCAAACTTGCCACCTCTGGCAACAATTATGCTGTGTGGGAGAAACAGTAA\n', 'GSVIVG01031739001': 'ATGAAAACGGAACTCTTTCTAGGTCATTTCCTCTTCAAACAAGAAAGAAGTAAAAGTTGCATACCAAATATGGACTCGATTTGGAGTCGTAGTGCCCTGTCCACAGCTTCGGACTTCCTCACTGCAATCTACTTCGCCTTCATCTTCATCGTCGCCAGGTTTTTCTTGGACAGATTCATCTATCGAAGGTTGGCCATCTGGTTATTGAGCAAGGGAGCTGTTCCATTGAAGAAAAATGATGCTACACTGGGAAAAATTGTAAAATGTTCGGAGTCTTTGTGGAAACTAACATACTATGCAACTGTTGAAGCATTCATTCTTGCTATTTCCTACCAAGAGCCATGGTTTAGAGATTCAAAGCAGTACTTTAGAGGGTGGCCAAATCAAGAGTTGACGCTTCCCCTCAAGCTTTTCTACATGTGCCAATGTGGGTTCTACATCTACAGCATTGCTGCCCTTCTTACATGGGAAACTCGCAGGAGGGATTTCTCTGTGATGATGTCTCATCATGTAGTCACTGTTATCCTAATTGGGTACTCATACATATCAAGTTTTGTCCGGATCGGCTCAGTTGTCCTTGCCCTGCACGATGCAAGTGATGTCTTCATGGAAGCTGCAAAAGTTTTTAAATATTCTGAGAAGGAGCTTGCAGCAAGTGTGTGCTTTGGATTTTTTGCCATCTCATGGCTTGTCCTACGGTTAATATTCTTTCCCTTTTGGGTTATCAGTGCATCAAGCTATGATATGCAAAATTGCATGAATCTATCGGAGGCCTATCCCATGTTGCTATACTATGTTTTCAATACAATGCTCTTGACACTACTTGTGTTCCATATATACTGGTGGATTCTTATATGCTCAATGATTATGAGACAGCTGAAAAATAGAGGACAAGTTGGAGAAGATATAAGATCTGATTCAGAGGACGATGAATAG\n'}
```

Comment: You do understand correctly and the genomic sequences are all in a file. However, there are a bunch of sequences in the file, not just these 3, and I need to pull the single sequence after a BLAST search. This is all coming after I run tBLASTx on said database, so I'm taking the GenBank IDs from my BLAST results (I already have a BLASTing program and parser set up for this), and using them to pull the genomic sequences from the database (tBLASTx gives better results than BLASTn for what I'm working on, but gives protein sequences rather than genomic sequences).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I figured out why the Python interpreter wasn't working while regex101 was; it was not reading the file as a string. I managed to get what I want by doing 
`target = open('Vvinifera_145_Genoscope.12X.cds.fa')
reader=target.read()
sequence = re.compile('(^>GSVIVT01031740001.*\n[ACGT\n]*)', re.M)
nucl = sequence.search(reader)
print nucl.groups()`

Thanks again for your help!